# PHP variable lost in scope issue

Tags: php, database-connection

Simple data access layer program.
I have a class with some protected variables for username password, etc.
I have a function that reads the an INI file and fills those protected variables. like this

```
class SqlAdapter
{
    protected $_connection

    protected $_username
    protected $_passwprd
    protected $_hostname

    public function __construct()
    {
        $params = parse_ini_file(__file__, 1);
        $this->_username = $params[...][...];
        ...
        ...
        [where the problem comes in]
        $this->_connection = mysqli_connect($this_hostname, ..., ...);
    }

    public function fectchMyStuff()
    {
        $result array()
        $query = mysqli_query($connection, $query, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
             $result[] = $row;
        }

        return json_encode($result);
    }
```

Now, when I run the connection stuff in the function it works just fine... but why isn't the protected variable "holding the charge" after the constructor is instantiated? Am I doingn something wrong?

Any advice? Point is, I don't want to have to rewrite that connection string every time I write a function that accesses my database... sort of defeats the purpose of reusable code and encapsulation and well, OOP all together!

thanks

Comment: `$query = mysqli_query($this->_connection, $query, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);`

Comment: and `$this_hostname`, did you mean `$this->_hostname`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was one approach I came up with...
I don't know if this is good or right! :)

addeed:

```
public function connect()
{
    return $this->conn = mysqli_connect($this->server, $this->user, $this->pwd, $this->db); 
}

function fetchMyStucc
{
    $query = mysqli_query($this->connect(), $query, ...)
```

seems to work.

thanks for the advice! it helped

Answer (score 0):

I think your `__construct` function is ok, but something seems not right in `fectchMyStuff`:

```
public function fectchMyStuff()
{
    $result array()
    // $query = mysqli_query($connection, $query, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);
    // should use $this->_connection
    $query = mysqli_query($this->_connection, $query, MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT);


    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
         $result[] = $row;
    }

    return json_encode($result);
}
```

#### update

```
 $this->_connection = mysqli_connect($this_hostname, ..., ...);
```

`$this_hostname`, do you mean `$this->_hostname`;

Comment: This was my first approach but I always get an error that _connection doesn't exist. It is losing scope for some reason... Notice: Undefined property: SqlAdapter::$connection in

Comment: in the code: `$this->_connection = mysqli_connect($this_hostname, ..., ...);`, `$this_hostname`, do you mean `$this->_hostname`?